# Retrieve XML Data Jquery + Append HTML

Tags: jquery

I want to create a list from a php xml file, so I read some tutorials and put together this:

```
$.blockUI();

           $.get('venuesxml.php', function (data) {

                $('#MenuList').append("<p><label><strong>Id</strong></label>
                                     <label><strong>venue type</strong></label></p>");

                $(data).find('marker').each(function () {

                    $('#MenuList').append("<p><label>" +

                    $(this).find('ID').text() + "</label><label>" +

                    $(this).find('venue_type').text() + "</label></p>");

                });

            });

            $.unblockUI();
```

However I noticed that this will only work if the xml looks like this:

```
<markers>
  <marker>

    <ID>1</ID>

    <venue_type>2</Name>

  </marker>
</markers>
```

However it looks like this:

```
<markers>
     <marker id="67" venue_type="2"/>
</markers>
```

How would I get the data in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve the XML attributes instead of nodes within `<marker>`

Try replacing `$(this).find('ID').text()` with `$(this).attr('id')` and `$(this).find('venue_type').text()` with `$(this).attr('venue_type')`

Answer (score 1):

try changing with this and see if this works for you:

```
$(this).text($(this).attr('id')) + "</label><label>" +

$(this).text($(this).attr('venue_type')) + "</label></p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attr` method:

```
$(data).find('marker').each(function () {
    var p = "<p>" +
               "<label>" + $(this).attr('id') + "</label>" +
               "<label>" + $(this).attr('venue_type') + "</label>" +
            "</p>"; 
    $('#MenuList').append(p)
});
```